# Function is executing inside button click automatically as default behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the code in below. There testFunction is executing automatically When the the button click is executing( default behavior of CMS I'm using. I want to override that behavior by skipping it in executing on button click). I want to skip executing the calling function named testFunction when the button click is executed. I tried below way without a success. Any input highly appreciated.

```
$(".classTest:not(selected)").find("button").on("click", function (){
      function testFunction(element,isSelected)
});

function testFunction(element, isSelected)(){ //code }
```

Answer (score 0):

One option might be to add a listener to an outer element (like the window), and on click, see if the target is one of those buttons - and if it is, call `stopPropagation` on the event to keep it from reaching the button.

```
window.addEventListener(
  'click',
  (e) => {
    if (e.target.matches('.classTest button')) {
      e.stopPropagation();
      // if you want something to happen when the button is clicked
      // put the code here
    }
  },
  true // add listener to capturing phase, not bubbling phase
);
```